# Calculate Normals for Procedural Shape

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

Given the code below. Taken from http://pastie.org/pastes/764327/text

```
    void CreateSphere(int PointRows, int PointsPerRow)
{
    NumVertices = (PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow + 2;
    Vertices = new SVertex[NumVertices];
    IndexVect.clear();  //to be sure it is empty
    float x,y,z;
    int i,j;
    double r;
    for (i = 1; i < (PointRows-1); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < PointsPerRow; j++)
        {
            y = 1.0 - float(i) / float(PointRows-1)*2.0;
            r = sin (acos(y));  //radius of the row
            x = r * sin(float(j) / float(PointsPerRow)*PI*2.0);     
            z = r * cos(float(j) / float(PointsPerRow)*PI*2.0);
        Vertices[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].x = x;
        Vertices[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].y = y;
        Vertices[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].z = z;
        Vertices[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].r = (float)(i) / float(PointRows);
        Vertices[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].g = 0.7;
        Vertices[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].b = (float)(j) / float(PointsPerRow);
    }

}
//The highest and deepest vertices:
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow].x = 0.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow].y = 1.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow].z = 0.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow].r = 1.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow].g = 0.7;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow].b = 1.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1].x = 0.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1].y = -1.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1].z = 0.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1].r = 1.0;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1].g = 0.7;
Vertices[(PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1].b = 1.0;

for (i = 1; i < (PointRows-2); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < (PointsPerRow-1); j++)
    {
        IndexVect.push_back((i-1)*PointsPerRow+j);
        IndexVect.push_back((i-1)*PointsPerRow+j+1);
        IndexVect.push_back((i)*PointsPerRow+j);

        IndexVect.push_back((i-1)*PointsPerRow+j+1);
        IndexVect.push_back((i)*PointsPerRow+j+1);
        IndexVect.push_back((i)*PointsPerRow+j);
    }

    IndexVect.push_back((i-1)*PointsPerRow+PointsPerRow-1);
    IndexVect.push_back((i-1)*PointsPerRow);
    IndexVect.push_back((i)*PointsPerRow+j);

    IndexVect.push_back((i)*PointsPerRow);
    IndexVect.push_back((i-1)*PointsPerRow);
    IndexVect.push_back((i)*PointsPerRow+j);
}       

//The triangles to the highest and deepest vertices:
for (j = 0; j< (PointsPerRow-1); j++)
{
    IndexVect.push_back(j);
    IndexVect.push_back(j+1);
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow);
}
IndexVect.push_back(j);
IndexVect.push_back(0);
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow);

for (j = 0; j< (PointsPerRow-1); j++)
{
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow+j);
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow+j+1);
    IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1);
}
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow+j);
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-3)*PointsPerRow);
IndexVect.push_back((PointRows-2)*PointsPerRow+1);
Indices = new GLuint[IndexVect.size()];  //allocate the required memory
for (i = 0; i < IndexVect.size(); i++)
{
    Indices[i] = IndexVect[i];
}
NumIndices = IndexVect.size();
IndexVect.clear();  //no longer needed, takes only memory
```

}

How would you calculate the normals using the resultant Vertices....?

I would then hope to use glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY) , and glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0, Normals) , along with glDrawElements to draw the resultant indices together with the normals.

I've had a go but it just looks wrong. The lighting appears to the left of the sphere, rather than below.

Apologies. I've not given the full picture here. Basically I'm trying to generate a random shape, by entering noise into the data.

If I use the following code at the end of the first nested loop:

```
Normals[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].x = x;
Normals[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].y = y;
Normals[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].z = z;
```

I am able to generate the correct normals for the sphere and it all looks fine.

However if I do this:

```
x=x+(noise3(x,y,z));
y=y+(noise3(x,y,z));
z=z+(noise3(x,y,z));
```

And then try to use:

```
Normals[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].x = x;
Normals[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].y = y;
Normals[(i-1)*PointsPerRow+j].z = z;
```

The normals look wrong for some faces. I want to loop through the resultant indices once the full shape has been created and then calculate the normal for each point, if that makes any sense....?

OK, here is what I got. It does not appear to work.It's probably completely wrong so go easy.

```
  for (j = 0; j < NumIndices-2; j=j+3)
   {

Ax = Vertices[Indices[j]].x;    Bx = Vertices[Indices[j+1]].x;   Cx = Vertices[Indices[j+2]].x;
Ay = Vertices[Indices[j]].y;   By = Vertices[Indices[j+1]].y;   Cy = Vertices[Indices[j+2]].y;
Az = Vertices[Indices[j]].z;   Bz = Vertices[Indices[j+1]].z;   Cz = Vertices[Indices[j+2]].z;

dms::Vector3 p1(Ax,Ay,Az);
dms::Vector3 p2(Bx,By,Bz);
dms::Vector3 p3(Cx,Cy,Cz);
dms::Vector3 V1= (p2 - p1);
dms::Vector3 V2 = (p3 - p1);
dms::Vector3 normal = V1.cross(V2);

Normals[j].x = normal[0];
Normals[j].y = normal[1];
Normals[j].z = normal[2];;

Normals[j+1].x = normal[0];
Normals[j+1].y = normal[1];
Normals[j+1].z = normal[2];;


Normals[j+2].x = normal[0];
Normals[j+2].y = normal[1];
Normals[j+2].z = normal[2];;
```

}

Edit ---

I was able to get a much better result by re-arranging the section where the 2 vectors are calculated. I changed the following:

```
dms::Vector3 V1= (p2 - p1);
dms::Vector3 V2 = (p3 - p1);
```

To:

```
dms::Vector3 V1= (p2 - p1);
dms::Vector3 V2 = (p1 - p3);
```

It still doesn't look quite right however, there is dark strip that runs along the front of the sphere, and the top of the sphere looks strange.

Many thanks for Kaganar's excellent answer which I will work through to resolve my remaining issues. Many thanks also to Bart!

Comment: The normals are simply calculated by subtracting the sphere's center coordinate from the vertex's coordinate. Normalize the resulting vector and you're done. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hmm, yes, I've missed off a huge part of what I'm trying to do. I want to calculate the normal for each point. I'll edit the main section.

Comment: So going by your update, you're not looking to generate normals for a sphere at all, but for an arbitrary random shape? (Generated by adding noise to a sphere)

Comment: Exactly, I have changed the title. Sorry about that... been trying to figure this out for way to long :-)

Comment: Then calculate a normal for each triangle. For each vertex, sum the normals for the triangles it's part of. And normalize that resulting vector.

Comment: That's basically where I am stuck. I can't work out how to loop through the resultant indices to grab the points for each triangle. I'm not sure how the triangles themselves are stored within the resultant Vertices array. How would one triangle be defined within the array?

Comment: A triangle is formed every three indices. So, index 0, 1, and 2 form a triangle. index 3, 4, and 5 form a triangle. The indices are simply vertex indices. So, the points for the first triangle are represented by something like vertex[index[0]], vertex[index[1]], and vertex[index[2]].

Comment: To elaborate on Bart's comment regarding computing the normals, I recommend setting all the normals to the zero vector, then going over all of the triangles and computing the normal for the triangle and adding that to the normal computed so far at each vertex. Then go over all the vertices and normalize the normal as mentioned. That way you don't have to do any extra book keeping -- just a couple of relatively straight forward loops and some math to calculate the normal of the triangle. (GIYF)

Comment: I've updated the main question with what I have come up with..... it doesn't appear to work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is one possible answer:

- Step 1: Set all vertex normals to the zero vector.
- Step 2: Calculate the normal of each triangle and add it to all vertices in each triangle.
- Step 3: Normalize all vertex normals.

Regarding the code you've posted at the time of writing this answer:

- It's not clear if the normals are initialized to the zero vector.
- You're assigning, not adding the normals to the vertex normals. (So step 2 isn't working right.) Furthermore, the normals you are adding to the vertex normals aren't themselves normalized. (A cross product is not automatically normalized -- you must normalize the result of the cross product.)
- You're not doing step 3 at all.

One further note: When you're normalizing, beware of close-to-zero-length vectors passed to your normalization function, especially if you're using noisily generated shapes. Since normalization is just dividing the components of the length of a vector, it's common to check to see if this length is close to zero before doing the division you'd normally expect. If it is close to zero, the output of such a normalize function is typically just the up vector (since a zero vector would cause spuriously dark results in most shading models.)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. My sphere almost looks right now, with the noise I can see that most of the triangles are correct, but some are dark, as you describe.